# Bank Conflict Issue in CUDA Shared Memory Access

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict, nsight-compute

I'm working on the render part of Assignment 2 for CMU's 15-418 course,which involves writing a high-performance renderer using CUDA. In my code, each CUDA thread is responsible for computing a single pixel, which is a data-parallel task.

To accelerate the computation, I'm using shared memory to store intermediate results:

```
__shared__ float smem_rads[32];
__shared__ float smem_colors[32 * 3];
__shared__ float smem_ps[32 * 3];

// Load values into the shared memory arrays every 32 indices

for (int index = 0; index < cuConstRendererParams.numCircles; ++index) {
    int index3 = 3 * index;
    if (index % 32 == 0) {
        __syncthreads();
        if (threadId < 32) {
            smem_ps[threadId] = cuConstRendererParams.position[index3 + threadId];
            smem_ps[threadId + 32] = cuConstRendererParams.position[index3 + threadId + 32];
            smem_ps[threadId + 64] = cuConstRendererParams.position[index3 + threadId + 64];
            smem_rads[threadId] = cuConstRendererParams.radius[index + threadId];
            smem_colors[threadId] = cuConstRendererParams.color[index3 + threadId];
            smem_colors[threadId + 32] = cuConstRendererParams.color[index3 + threadId + 32];
            smem_colors[threadId + 64] = cuConstRendererParams.color[index3 + threadId + 64];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // Access the shared memory values later
    float3 p = ((float3*)smem_ps)[index % 32];
    float rad = smem_rads[index % 32];
    float rgb = ((float3*)smem_colors)[index % 32];
}
```

However, when analyzing the code using Nsight Compute, I'm encountering bank conflicts.
[image: bank conflict showed by Nsight Compute]

Could someone please explain the reason for these bank conflicts and suggest ways to resolve them? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations to optimize my shared memory access patterns.

Other Relevant Information:

- CUDA version: 12.2
- GPU model: NVIDIA RTX 3090

I try to change 32 to other number, but it does not work.

**EDIT: Thank you for all your assistance. I have used `__ldg` instructions for loading const global memory, and the bank conflicts have disappeared. However, it appears that bank conflicts were not the primary factor impacting performance.**

Comment: First of all: Did you remove the [`__syncthreads()` instructions necessary](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions) before and after writing to the shared memory in order to shorten the presented code or did you forget to put them in the code, which would cause a race condition?

Comment: Generally my understanding is that bank conflict numbers in that table can include ones caused by other things (L1 cache access I guess). So to see actual "fixable" bank conflicts, you need to look at "L1 Wavefronts Shared Excessive" in the [source page](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightCompute/index.html#source-page). See e.g. [this post on the Nvidia Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/shared-memory-bank-conflicts-and-nsight-metric/115731/15).

Comment: Another indication that it cannot be a true bank conflict is the low number of conflicts compared to overall instructions. 700 million instructions result in 7 thousand "bank conflicts". That would be one in 100,000 operations. If it was one of the shown instructions, we would expect something in the order of one in seven, right?

Comment: There is nothing in the column of "L1 Wavefronts Shared Excessive". Does it mean that no bank conflicts? Thanks, @paleonix

Comment: I have put the nessary `__syncthreads()` in the code. What does it mean "Other" in the figure. Thanks, @Homer512

Comment: At least none in the shared memory part of the L1 cache. Loading a `float3` takes three wavefronts but that doesn't count as excessive as it still gives maximum throughput. I observed these conflicts in the table changing when using different [L1 caching intrinsics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#load-functions-using-cache-hints) in the past, but I don't think performance improved and I'm not sure anymore if they completely vanished.

Comment: Have you tried `__shared__ float smem_rads[32+1];
__shared__ float smem_colors[32 * 3+1];
__shared__ float smem_ps[32 * 3+1];`? a number not power of 2

Comment: @JaehongLee That kind of padding is only needed for "column-wise" access. If this were an issue there would be many more conflicts and "L1 Wavefronts Shared Excessive" would mark these lines of code.

Comment: BTW You could perhaps use 256 registers/thread and loop unrolling (to prevent dynamic indexing) instead of shared memory altogether.

Comment: Do you have many stalls on short scoreboard? That is how you know that the bottleneck could be the shared memory.